# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. On default project

Tags: android, gradle

I downloaded the recent version of android studio from android website. Installed it, corrected java path error and set up the SDK. 
Then I created a default Hello World project and try to run it on emulator.

There was no manual change done in the project and everything was generated automatically. 
When gradle build started, it failed with below error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

I tried enabling multiDexSupport in gradle.build file, but no luck.
Anyone can please help me with what could be wrong with default generated project .

Please help. 
Rajan

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

Post your `build.gradle`  . Version `Conflicts/Same Library` calling creates this problem .

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

At first Add `multidex` in your `build.gradle` section

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Clean-Rebuild-Sync**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

> https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html